# Show that $X$ is a gradient field.

Tags: analysis

Let $X : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ a polynomial vector field, the restriction on the unit sphere is a gradient field. Show that $X$ is a gradient field.

Any idea or hint about this question?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am writing the answer as I realized now:

**Remark 1**: Let $P, Q : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ polynomial with $P|_{(a,b)}=Q|_{(a,b)}$ where $a < b$. Then holds $P(x)=Q(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Remark 2**: Let $P,Q: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ two polynomials with $P|_{D^n}=Q|_{D^n}$, where $D^n= \left \{ p \in \mathbb{R}^n | \left \|p  \right \| \leq1 \right \}$. Then holds $P(p)=Q(p)$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Write $X=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_ie_i$, where $X_i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a polynomial. Thus, for all polynomials $\frac{\partial X_i}{\partial x_m}$. From Poincare theorem for gradient fields holds: for all $j,k \in \left \{ 1, ..., n \right \}$ $\frac{\partial X_j}{\partial x_k}|_{D^n}=\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial x_j}|_{D^n}$. From Remark 2, $\frac{\partial X_j}{\partial x_k}(p)=\frac{\partial X_k}{\partial x_j}(p)$ for every $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Then, again followis by Poincare that $X$ a global gradient field is unit sphere.